# Does Yom Tov end the "Shloshim" period?

Tags: yom-tov, mourning-aveilus

I know that if people are sitting shiva, and a Yom Tov occurs in the middle of the shiva period, shiva immediately ends.

Does this same "quick end" rule apply to the *shloshim* (30 day mourning period) as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Shloshim is cancelled if Shiva ended before the holiday started. ShA YD 399:3