# Does Yom Kippur end mourning

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, mourning-aveilus, aseres-yemei-teshuva, sitting-shiva

In [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64088/33665) Yom Tov ends shloshim and shiva, my question is does the same rule apply to Yom Kippur if a close relative dies during the days of repentance?

Or is Yom Kippur different from other holidays in this respect? I ask because in many respects like melacha, the laws for Yom Kippur are more like Shabbat than a Yom Tov.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed Yom Kippur ends mourning, as the OU [writes](https://outorah.org/p/29450/)

> Shiv'a ends if a Jewish festival, Rosh Hashana, or **Yom Kippur**
> intervenes.
>
> Shloshim ends if a Jewish festival, Rosh Hashana, or **Yom Kippur**
> intervenes.
>
> If two of those holidays occur within the first seven days after
> burial, the first one will break shiv'a and the second one will break
> shloshim.

Answer (score 1):

SA [OC 548:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.548.11?lang=bi)

> ראש השנה ויום הכפורים חשיבי כרגלים לבטל האבילות

> Rosh Hashana and Yom Kipur are treated like festivals with respect to nullifying mourning

The [Kaf Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.548.56.1?lang=bi) explains that even though there is no simcha mentioned on them like the other holidays, there’ they are still considered together with the holidays:

> ואע"ג דלא כתיב בהו שמחה אחז"ל שמבטלים את האבילות כמו הרגלים דכולהו הוקשו להדדי בתורה דכתיב אלה מועדי ה' ויש בכללם ר"ה ויוה"כ. לבוש

Comment: Note this was a dispute in the Mishna (MK 3:6)